# Facebook Messenger: How to send an array of items in Airline templates?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Is it possible to send an array of items through any of Facebook's Airline Update template as defined here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/airline-update-template

If not, how do I replicate the airline template using a Generic Template?

Comment: What do you mean with array of items?

Comment: An array of flights options. Essentially, I want to show a list of flights after a query, and the format of this template seemed great for that.